# No feeds displaying in the feed section

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: motorola
- Device Model: MotoG3

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (35)

Earlier it used to show feeds on various stack exchange site.. But now only an annoying disoriented random single post is shown..

I've cleared the data.. Reinstalled the app.. Still no change

Screenshot:

> [image]

Comment: As seen in the dupe, it's not really a bug. You simply have no activity.

Comment: Yea but earlier even when I've no activity it shows different stack exchange websites' hot topics and discussions.. Thanks anyways

Comment: See the comments under the other question, there is a link to chat discussion where Kasra (SE developer who worked on the app in the past) explains why it happens, and why it can't be fixed.

Comment: By now... your issue should have been fixed (since you got comments reply). If no, please let us know, because it shouldn't happen.

Comment: Yes the feed is active now.. Due to this post lol.. Thanks